# Excel automatic value for certain values of previous column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am making a spreadsheet that is three rows, and I want the third row to be dependent on the second.  There are two possible values for the second row, and 4 for the third row.  Let's say that column 2 has values (1, 2) and column 3 has values (1, 2, 3, 4).  If a cell in column 2 has the value 2, the cell in that row but in column 3 should be 4.  But if the cell in col 2 has value 1, the cell in column 3 should have a dropdown with options 1, 2, and 3, but NOT 4.  Right now, I have drop downs in both columns with all values, but how can I add this dependency?

Comment: You are asking about the content of column 3 being dependent upon the content in column 2 but also you are asking about three rows. Can you show a sample in some way of what you mean?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for column 3 to be dependent upon column 2 results, but you are also asking about 3 rows so it is not really clear what you are asking. If you have a value of 2 in the cell in column 2 the result in column 3 should be 4. Would the use of data validation offering 1,2, or 3  be acceptable as a solution?